# Graphics bug in Unity 5

Tags: graphics, 3d, unity-game-engine

I've started working on new project using unity 5.
I export a model from Autodesk Maya 2017 (FBX format).
Everything is going well until I get closer to a wall, or other object.
Then the texture disappear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your camera renders on a specific bound where the object being rendered is cut off. Try setting the camera's clipping plane's Near to 0.01

[image]

There are two values you can set to configure Clipping planes, Near is the point where the camera starts to render objects and Far is the point where the camera stops rendering objects. Think of these values as render bounds, one at the beginning (Near) and one at the end (Far).

Comment: You can see that the Clipping settings are correct in the first image.
I think that the problem is more scale-related, I see 0.4 camera scale, probably to fit the model scale which is also incorrect.